# create Web Service client using JDK1.5

Tags: java-5, webservices-client

I need to create a web service client using JDK1.5 ... Is it possible ?

I know in JDK1.6 there are a `wsimport` utility that generates the artifacts for the service, and hered that earlier versions used `wsdl2java`, but cannot found in my JDK installation .

```
java -version
java version "1.5.0_05"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_05-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_05-b05, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You can create a web service with any language that can open a network socket.  Whether you'd want to or not is another matter.

Comment: Ya I know that.. but i am hear talking with some utilities that make it more easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use JAX-WS.

See:
http://codeproject.com/KB/java/edujini_webservice_java.aspx